# How can we use slider inside a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need a slider working inside a loop for that I am using the below code

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div id="content">




<?php 


$attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'order' => '',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image')
    );  
echo "aaaaa".count($attachments);   
?>


<?php if(count($attachments)!=0){ ?>
<div id="portfolio-gallery">
    <ul id="slideshow_detail">
        <?php 
         foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
        $getimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att_id, 'room-gallery', true);
        $roomimage = $getimage[0];
        echo '<li>
        <h3></h3>
        <span>'.$roomimage.'</span>
        <p></p>
        <img src="'.$roomimage.'" alt="" class="thumb-slide" />
        </li>';
         }
        ?>
    </ul>

    <div id="wrapper1">
        <div id="fullsize">
            <div id="imgprev" class="imgnav" title="Previous Image"></div>
            <div id="imglink"></div>
            <div id="imgnext" class="imgnav" title="Next Image"></div>
            <div id="image"></div>
            <div id="information">
                <h3></h3>
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnails">
            <div id="slideleft" title="Slide Left"></div>
            <div id="slidearea">
                <div id="slider-room"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="slideright" title="Slide Right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 

    $('slideshow_detail').style.display='none';
    $('wrapper1').style.display='block';
    var slideshow_detail=new TINY.slideshow_detail("slideshow_detail");
    window.onload=function(){

        slideshow_detail.auto=true;
        slideshow_detail.speed=5;
        slideshow_detail.link="linkhover";
        slideshow_detail.info="information";
        slideshow_detail.thumbs="slider-room";
        slideshow_detail.left="slideleft";
        slideshow_detail.right="slideright";
        slideshow_detail.scrollSpeed=4;
        slideshow_detail.spacing=25;
        slideshow_detail.active="#fff";
        slideshow_detail.init("slideshow_detail","image","imgprev","imgnext","imglink");
    }
//-->  
</script>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

By using this code slider is working only once;I need a slider that working  under a loop .
ie I have to add multiple post,each post having multiple images .I have to show details of each post and showing images of each post  using a slider

Comment: you include the JS on each while loop. So if it works it gets registered multiple times. Move your JS out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I feel maybe the **while loop**, beginning at the top could be the problem. Why not use an if statement. I'm not familiar with your "while" syntax. I've only ever seen the following:

```
<?php while( someCondition() ): ?>

    //statements in here

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Or maybe try an if statement instead:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
    //all slider code here
<?php } else { ?>
   //give a 'there are no posts' message
<?php endif; ?>
```

also what wordpress plugin are you running? Without knowing that, it's a bit difficult to trouble shoot this problem.

Comment: http://themomenthotel.com/new/los-angeles-accommodations/ By using above code slider is working for only one post .In the remaining post images are displayed one by one